# MinGW gcc does nothing

Tags: c, gcc, mingw

I installed gcc with the GUI installer MinGW Installation Manager. After it installed the basics, I manually checked and installed mingw32-binutils and mingw32-gcc. I added the directory to my path. I can use the command in powershell. If I use gcc alone I get an error because i didn't input any file, if I put in a .txt it tells me it's not recognized. So that part works as it should.

However once I put a file, main.c, whether or not it's real code (basic main with hello world) or a random string or character, absolutely nothing happens, no message, and the command terminates. So basically I enter gcc and the prompt immediately asks for another command. I reinstalled it twice.

The command:

```
gcc -o a.exe main.c
```

I'm using Windows 10 if that can help.

Comment: What command line are you using?

Comment: "*if I put in a .txt it tells me it's not recognized.*" who does not recognise what, please?

Comment: What do you mean by: ` if I put in a .txt it tells me it's not recognized.`?   Could you clarify what you actually did to install mingw?

Comment: What do you get by just issuing `gcc`?

Comment: @user3629249: by that I meant that it acts as normal, telling me compilation doesnt work with a .txt. So the command isn't totally unresponsive. I installed gcc with the MinGW manager GUI.

Comment: @alk: by entering only gcc, I get "fatal error, no input files"

Comment: If gcc compiles fine it does not issue/print/show/log anything. That's the IXish way: No news, is good news. Do an `ls -alrt` and see what's new at the bottom of the list. :-)

Comment: @alk: NO new file is created. It does absolutely nothing.

Comment: How do you open die console window into which you observe this?

Comment: What do you expect it to do? Are you sure it didn't silently create `a.exe`? That would be normal behaviour; AFAICT, it's doing exactly what it's supposed to, and you just don't know what that is.

Comment: I had the same issue and it seems that the MinGW website is no longer up at the moment. The only solution for me was to redownload gcc using this method: https://preshing.com/20141108/how-to-install-the-latest-gcc-on-windows/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other things to install. See the list that you can find in the [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/howto_install_the_mingw_gcc_compiler_suite) site :

```
binutils (bin)
mingw-runtime (dev and dll)
w32api
Required runtime libraries for GCC:
    mpc (dll)
    mpfr (dll)
    gmp (dll)
    pthreads (dev and dll)
    iconv (dll)
    zlib
    gettext
gcc-core (bin and dev and dll)
```

Otherwise, you can install all the required packages via the GUI manager provided with the installation of MinGW.

Comment: I can find some of these packages in the GUI manager, lik mpc, gmp, pthreads, but not all, like iconv. Do they have another name? EDIT: I thought the manager would just install all the requiered packages

Comment: If I recall, you have some packages checked, but not all the required. binutils, mingw-runtime and gcc-core are the most important I believe. Try with them at first

Answer (score 0):

It's a path issue.
I had the same issue.
Try this in powershell set the path to only include mingw like this:
$Env:PATH = "C:\ProgramData\mingw64\mingw64\bin"
Then run gcc and it will actually try to compile.

Comment: You could also use this - to save and restore the path environment variable.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47480143/powershell-script-to-take-backup-of-all-environment-variables-save-it-in-a-fil