# PowerShell script to take backup of all environment variables & save it in a file

Tags: powershell, command-line, environment-variables, backup, command-prompt

I am new to PowerShell and recently started learning about some of its commands.

Now I am looking to try adding, editing and deleting any path entry from the environment Path variable (System).

But I am concerned about the case if anything goes wrong, so I want to take backup of all environment variables in case I need to restore.

I have the following cmdlet to display specific variable onto the screen, but can anyone let me know how to take backup of all environment variables (both system and user) to a text file through a `.ps1` PowerShell script?

```
Get-ChildItem Env:Path
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note: **PowerShell's `env:` drive only reflects the environment variables of the *current process*** - to *persistently* change the system's or the current user's environment variables, you must use the .NET framework directly - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38928399/45375).

The following snippet, which uses `env:`, therefore only shows how to **save and restore all environment variables of the current *process***:

```
# Save all the process' environment variables in CLIXML format.
Get-ChildItem env: | Export-CliXml ./env-vars.clixml

# ... modify the env. variables

# Restore the previously saved env. variables.
Import-CliXml ./env-vars.clixml | % { Set-Item "env:$($_.Name)" $_.Value }
```

Note that this will not *remove* any *new* env. variables you may have created in the meantime - extra work is needed to eliminate those: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77320012/45375).

---

Note: **`Export-CliXml` and `Import-CliXml`** are being used, because they **enable robust round-tripping (serialization / deserialization) of values** (although you cannot *generally* recreate objects of the very same *type*, only deserialized *look-alikes*).

By contrast, using something like `Get-ChildItem env: > ./env-vars.txt` or its equivalent, `Get-ChildItem env: | Out-File ./env-vars.txt` simply saves the `Get-ChildItem` output as *plain text* *the way it displays in the console*, which is not a format suitable for *machine parsing* (deserialization).

---

**Optional reading: why `Import-CliXml ./env-vars.clixml | Set-Item` *should* work, but doesn't:**

`Set-Item` is designed to bind parameter values via the pipeline, notably `-LiteralPath` (alias `-PSPath`) and `-Value`.

Therefore, if `Set-Item` receives objects through the pipeline that have *properties* by those names (`.PSPath`, `.Value`), they *should* automatically bind to the `-PSPath` (`-LiteralPath`) and `-Value` parameters, enabling invocation such as `... | Set-Item` - so there *should* be no need for explicit enumeration and explicit parameter-passing via `%` (`ForEach-Object`), as used above.

Unfortunately, however, as of Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core v6.0.1, the `-Value` parameter is defined in a way that *also* binds the input object *as a whole* to `-Value` (`ValueFromPipeline`), which - given that `-Value` is defined generically as type `[System.Object]` - *invariably* takes precedence over looking for the object's `.Value` *property* (`ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName`) - in other words: **no input object, irrespective of its type, is ever bound by its `.Value` property - any input object is bound *as itself***.

In the case at hand, the objects output by `Import-CliXml` are of type `[Deserialized.System.Collections.DictionaryEntry]`; they are bound to `-Value`, and then converted to a *string* when the environment variable is set (environment variables can only ever contain *string* values); the string representation of that type is `System.Collections.DictionaryEntry` - irrespective of its `.Value` property - and that generic string is therefore - uselessly - set as the environment variable's value.

This problematic behavior has been reported in [GitHub issue #5543](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5543).

Comment: Is there anything that can be done to make it the exact same type? Like filter the input and replace with regex for classes and such...

Comment: @ZaxLofful: Note that the problem at hand is the broken behavior of `Set-Item`, not `Import-CliXml`'s deserialization behavior. Therefore, given that environment-variable values are always _strings_, the workaround in the answer (`Import-CliXml ... | % { Set-Item ... }`) is sufficient. `Import-CliXml` itself works as designed, though note that, as stated, that means that many types are deserialized as _look-alikes_ of their original types - which, however, is often sufficient.

Comment: Actually my question pertains to you last point, not the former (understood that Set-Item sucks). You still mentioned in your comment that they are "look-alikes",  which is what I was referring to "Is there anything that can be done to make it the exact same type?'

Comment: @ZaxLofful: I don't think there is a generic solution - you won't be able to recreate _live_ objects (those whose properties represent realtime system state), you won't be able to recreate objects whose types have no public constructors, ... The best you can do is to special-case individual types; it work for `[Deserialized.System.Collections.DictionaryEntry]`, for instance.

Answer (score -1):

You can always send your output to a file, by "piping" (done with a |) the output of a command to a file with the [Out-File cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-5.1):

```
Get-ChildItem env: | Out-File test.txt
```

"test.txt" is the name of your file.

Comment: Your command exports the path values into file, but the long paths are being cut and replaced with `...`, can something be done about that ?

Comment: @VickyDev: You can use [`-Width <max-column-width>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-5.1#optional-parameters), but that still doesn't make `Out-File`'s output suitable for later deserialization.