# In Powershell how to store the current environment variables and restore them as they were

Tags: powershell

I am looking for a method to save all environment variables of the currently running process to a variable and restore them back from that saved state.

This is how far I got:

```
$OldEnvironment = Get-ChildItem env:
try
{
    # Manipulate a variable
    $env:PATH="C:\My\Utilities\Path;$env:PATH"
    # Remove some
    Remove-Item -Path Env:ALLUSERSPROFILE
    Remove-Item -Path Env:APPDATA
    Remove-Item -Path Env:LOCALAPPDATA
    # Set a new one which we presume did not exist before
    Set-Item -Path env:NEWSHINYVARIABLE "FOOBAR"
    # Output current environment
    Get-ChildItem env:|ft
}
finally
{
    # Restore ...
    $OldEnvironment|%{ Set-Item -Path "Env:$($_.Name)" "$($_.Value)" }
    # ... alas there's a glitch here:
    Get-ChildItem -Path env:NEWSHINYVARIABLE|ft
    # NEWSHINYVARIABLE _still_ exists
}
```

Now my issue is to make sure that variables set inside the `try` block don't leak out (like `NEWSHINYVARIABLE` does). Removed variables aren't an issue, because they will simply get created anew.

How can also remove variables currently contained in `env:` but not stored in `$OldEnvironment` with a concise one-liner? (Please note: I do not want to resort to modules and background jobs which - as I understand - contain their own private environment. I want to stay with the `try .. finally` method structurally.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object) to compare the content of the [`Env:` PowerShell drive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Environment_Provider) before and after, and take appropriate actions to restore the values of preexisting or remove newly added environment variables:

```bash
# Set some sample env. vars.
$env:foo='original foo'
$env:bar='original bar'

# Get the current list of env. vars. and their values
$envVarsBefore = Get-ChildItem Env:

try {
  # Perform sample operations that add, update, and delete environment variables.
  $env:foo='changed foo'
  $env:bar=$null # Remove $env:bar
  $env:goaway='yes' # define a new var.
} finally {
  # Restore the original environment, including removal of newly added variables.
  Compare-Object -PassThru $envVarsBefore (Get-ChildItem Env:) | 
    ForEach-Object {
      # A newly added or updated variable: remove it.
      # (If it was updated, it'll be restored with its original value below.)
      if ($_.SideIndicator -eq '=>') {
        Remove-Item Env:$($_.Name)
      }
      else { # $_.SideIndicator -eq '<='
        # Restore a deleted variable or a modified's variable original value.
        Set-Item Env:$($_.Name) $($_.Value)
      }
    }
}

# Check if the original environment was restored:
Get-Item Env:foo, Env:bar, Env:goaway
```

The last command in the code above prints the original (restored) values of `$env:foo` and `$env:bar` and - as expected - reports an error for the no-longer-extant `$env:goaway` variable.

Note:

- `Get-ChildItem Env:` emits [`System.Collections.DictionaryEntry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.DictionaryEntry) instances, each representing an env. var. as a key(name)-value pair.
- When `Compare-Object` processes objects that do *not* implement the [`System.IComparable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IComparable) interface, it falls back to comparing objects by their `.ToString()` values. Fortunately, such instances have *meaningful* string representations that reflect both the entry key (the env. var *name*) and value (the env. var. *value*); e.g.:

  ```bash
  # -> e.g. (on Windows): '[OS, Windows_NT]'
  (Get-Item Env:OS).ToString()
  ```

Comment: Thanks so much. Is there any difference to speak of between `Set-Item` (my snippet) and `Set-Content` (your snippet) when setting the variables?

Comment: Glad to her it helped, @0xC0000022L. No, there's no practical difference, and for symmetry I've updated the answer to use `Set-Item`. Technically, however, the equivalent of `$env:foo = 1` is `Set-Content foo 1`, because that's how [namespace variable notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55036515/45375) works.